# Is it possible to embed a QGIS map with all the information I added, in my web site?

Tags: qgis, embeddable-web-maps

I am not a cartographer or geography student. I work in a network organization for developmental policy and I need a good software which enables me to record the cities in which our members work on a worldwide map. The problem is, that I must be able to embed that map in our website.

Do you know if that is possible with a map from QGIS? And if it's not possible, do you know a software which I could use for that purpose?

Comment: Do you want a static graphic (just a picture of the map with cities), or an interactive map (that can be zoomed/clicked on)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the QGIS desktop, short answer, no. You would need to make all the data you have in the QGIS map into a web map. Web mapping isn't overly straight forward, and if you do not have experience with Java Script and web servers, it can be over whelming. An option would be to look at the following web mapping applications: MapBox, CartoDB, and Google Map Engine. With these applications you can make maps and embed them into your website. Each will have different aspects to them, such as how many features you can show, how to put data into the map, views per month, etc. Each have a free version, as well as paid versions.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer. I hoped I had found a good way to embed an interactive map in the website with Qgis, but I will have a look at your suggestions then.

Comment: You will be able to use QGIS to make some of the data. I have used MapBox and CartoDB to do this very thing. I found that GeoJSON is the best data format for web maps such as MapBox and CartoDB.

Comment: I just looked up your suggestions and besides the Google Map Engine all of them require a fee. Do you know any which is maybe for free ?

@Erica: sorry I forgot to say: it should be an interactive one.

Comment: Look at CartoDB. I have a free account with them. You are limited to the number of layers you can show on the free web map. https://cartodb.com/signup 

Signup and you will default to the free account

Comment: Look into the Qgis Leaflet plugin. I have checked it out a little bit and it will write most everything that you need for a Leaflet web-based map.

Comment: or - if a simple imagemage fits your needs - look at the html image plugin https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/imagemap_plugin/

Answer (score 3):

**Update** (based on Tom Chadwin's comment):

qgis2leaf and qgis-ol3 have now been merged into **qgis2web**.

---

It's not clear from your question which features you expect from the web map but have a look at

- **qgis2leaf** http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/leaflet_maps_with_qgis2leaf.html which exports a Leaflet map directly from QGIS desktop
- QGIS to OpenLayers 3 **qgis-ol3** as described in http://www.digital-geography.com/top-5-qgis-plugins

Comment: qgis2leaf and qgis-ol3 have now been merged into qgis2web.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution to add your QGis map as an Iframe to your website:

1. Open QGis
2. Plugins -> install GIS Cloud Publisher
3. Create an account or/and login with your account
4. Publish your map to GIS Cloud Publisher
5. Go to GIS Cloud Publisher and click on "Share or Publish"
6. Select Embed and copy the Iframe code
7. Add the Iframe code to your website
8. Done!

Answer (score 0):

Question is a bit old, but still among the first to show on Google Search.

1. Tutorial

So here is a tutorial I found useful for publishing QGIS data on the web using the mentioned QGIS2Web plugin:

https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/web_mapping_with_qgis2web.html

2. Alternative Way

It seems that Geoserver is also able to visualize a Shapefile:

https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/gettingstarted/shapefile-quickstart/index.html

I beleive there are futher ways fo doing this.